# Can a UWP App Self Activate Its Window?

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10

```
public class MainViewModel MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    Window window { get; set; }

    public MyViewModel()
    {
        window = Window.Current;
    }

    async void MyWebSocketService_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.PropertyName)
        {
            case "ActivateWindow"
            ActivateWindow();
            break;
        }
    }

    void ActivateWindow()
    {
        await Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
        {
            window.Activate();
            window.CoreWindow.Activate();
        });
    }
}
```

I'm trying to get a hidden or minimized UWP app to regain focus in the OS upon a WebSocket notification.  This is the code I tried.  It fires but nothing happens. Is there a way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Comment: When you are minimized you actually get suspended, and then you can't run any code until the user resumes your app. What is your scenario? is it for testing or is it a production scenario?

Comment: It would be for a production scenario.  I have a Win32 companion app and I'd like it to be able to switch focus back to the UWP app.  It seems calling Process.Start("UWPAppName:") does the trick and is an acceptable workaround.

Comment: Yes, that will work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A UWP app cannot resume itself from minimized state because its execution state is suspended (and therefore can't run any code). The resume needs to be triggered externally, either by the user or by another running app, which can activate the suspended UWP app via any of the supported app activation APIs, for example doing a launch via protocol - as you have already figured out.

Comment: Somebody is going to think "but wait, background tasks are not suspended!"

Comment: @Hans Passant: Yes, but background tasks don't have foreground rights and therefore can't bring themselves or other apps to the foreground by design.

Comment: A simple timer will run as well. Perhaps your comment should be edited into the answer?

Comment: @ispiro No, it won't. When your app is suspended, timers won't run anymore.

Comment: I'll have to take your word for that, because my `Device.StartTimer` (Xamarin.Forms) does run on Android, iOS, and on UWP on desktop. And I can't test on Windows 10 Mobile because we're currently using .net standard 2.0 which can't run on Windows 10 mobile.

Comment: @ispiro It shouldn't run with UWP on desktop either. You have to test this without debugger attached, because with debugger we will not suspend the process. Minimize the app and you will see that all threads gets suspended and no more app code can run.

Comment: You're right. I thought being in the background would be the same as being minimized. (When focus is on a different window, it does work.)